Why am I getting the Sign in as popup in Stack Overflow and doing nothing?
I am getting frustrated with two issues with the Stack Overflow website.

It continuously asked me to sign in with Google even though I was already logged in.
If I try to click on the sign, it then it does nothing.
and the session is also not persistent. It keeps logging me out after one day.


What is going on with the Stack Overflow website? I tried updating the system, and browser, but I still have this issue.

OS: macOS v12 (Monterey)
Browser: Google Chrome (version 123.0.6312.124)


Part of this

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda I would assume that giving you sign in popup would only be for situations when you are not already signed in. I those popping up for a while on every page I opened on Stack Overflow today.

I got confirmation it was a bug that was resolved in the meantime.

Well, this was a bug for the last week. and session persistent like from the last month.

@SachinKumar so it is fixed now for you as well?

@ResistanceIsFutile sure, but the bug was likely that SO failed to detect the user already signed in, can't know why though. Hopefully a dev will hop by and explain.

Yes @ShadowWizardLoveZelda it is fixed now. Thanks

Can confirm, this just happened to me. Shown a "log in" prompt on the inbox drop-down, even though I am clearly logged in, and navigating to a new page made it work correctly again.

There is still an issue with the session lifetime. Why it keep me logout, afair the session lasted for one year but now it logout from StackOverflow after 2-3 days?
